# How to draw a quadratic curved line between two text objects within a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier

Goal per subject.

code snip:

```
var canvas= document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx= canvas.getContext('2d');   
canvas.width= 520;
canvas.height= 405;
ctx.font = "15pt Verdana";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;

// text 1
ctx.fillText("me and my dog puddie", 210, 90);  
// text 2
ctx.fillText("you and many many crazy nuts", 210, 130); 
// draw a quadratic bezier curved line between the these 2 text blocks
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(65,60,50)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(210,100);
ctx.bezierCurve(230,250,130,160,160,100);
ctx.stroke();

/* outcome:
no line were drawn between these two text objects
*/
```

I have a very limited understanding of a quadratic curved line

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
ctx.bezierCurve(230,250,130,160,160,100);
```

to

```
ctx.bezierCurveTo(230,250,130,160,160,100);
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: May, I was careless! Thanks. btw, do you how to calculate for each parameters?  Say, I want the x of text 1 as starting point of the curve line and the y of text 2 as ending point.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `quadraticCurveTo` for quadratic curves, `bezierCurveTo` is for cubic curves.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(210,100); // move to the start
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(230, 130, 160, 100); // draw quadractic curve
ctx.stroke();
```

See [Bezier and quadratic curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Bezier_and_quadratic_curves) in the Canvas Tutorial.